# alternative to method_missing in Chef 13

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, upgrade, chef-recipe, cookbook

upgraded the system from chef 12 to 13 facing issue with method_missing
found from some links that method_missing is deprecated is there any alternative for this.

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  # Build the set of names to check for a valid resource
  lookup_path = ["application_#{name}"]
  run_context.cookbook_collection.each do |cookbook_name, cookbook_ver|
    if cookbook_name.start_with?("application_")
      lookup_path << "#{cookbook_name}_#{name}"
    end
  end
  lookup_path << name
  resource = nil
  lookup_path = ["application_#{name}"]
  # Try to find our resource
  lookup_path.each do |resource_name|
    begin
      Chef::Log.debug "Trying to load application resource #{resource_name} for #{name}"
      resource = super(resource_name.to_sym, *args, &block)
      break
    rescue NameError => e
      # Works on any MRI ruby
      if e.name == resource_name.to_sym || e.inspect =~ /\b#{resource_name}\b/
        next
      else
        raise e
      end
    end
  end
  raise NameError, "No resource found for #{name}. Tried #{lookup_path.join(', ')}" unless resource
  # Enforce action :nothing in case people forget
  resource.action :nothing
  # Make this a weakref to prevent a cycle between the application resource and the sub resources
  resource.application WeakRef.new(self)
  resource.type name
  @sub_resources << resource
  resource
end
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? Please be more specific. `method_missing` is not deprecated; it's a fundamental part of the core ruby language. Perhaps some specific usage of this method has been marked as "deprecated" in this gem?? (But I don't know what, because you haven't explained the problem clearly.)

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc052-missing-method-missing.md#compatibility) what you're talking about? *"Stack traces for resource declarations will usually no longer contain `method_missing` (and will instead contain the name of the resources)."* -- It does not say "`method_missing` is deprecated". What does the code above have to do with stack traces? Are you facing an issue where you were *relying* on `method_missing` in the stack trace?

Comment: this que is more specific to chef rather than ruby  *No resource found for php. Tried application_php* resource is available but still, it says not found  ref:-  https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc052-missing-method-missing.md

Comment: What does *"No resource found for php"* have to do with your question above? Where is the code that triggers this error? Have you defined a `Chef::Resource`, such as what's shown in that example, and were relying on an implicitly defined Chef DSL? If you have an error, please show us the full error, and the code that triggers it. In other words, please provide a [mcve] of the problem; I still don't know what you're asking.

Comment: i have provided you the code block in the que where raises the exception  raise NameError, "No resource found for #{name}. Tried #{lookup_path.join(', ')}" unless resource here resource is the return type of missing_method.

Comment: You have not provided a [mcve]. You have provided a method with no context. How can I  **reproduce** your problem? You said the error has got something to do with *"No resource found for php"*, but where is the definition of this `php` thing? Why is `method_missing` being called in the first place?

Comment: That is my code, and it is fully compatible with Chef 13 as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I see the real question in comments. The application_php cookbook was never upgraded to work with the rest of the newer application cookbook suite. You would have to write your own version of it.

For anyone else finding this question via Google: the `method_missing` thing is a total red herring. The user was confused because in Chef we removed a `method_missing`-based syntax for node attributes. This is unrelated to my use of it for subresource management.